# Melhor forma de trabalhar com dados hierárquicos no MySQL para um sistema com cadastro constante na hierarquia

Tags: mysql, dados-hierárquicos

Eu tenho uma tabela onde armazeno cadastro de usuários onde cada usuário foi indicado por outro usuário, dai então mantenho uma coluna **ID** e uma coluna **PARENT_ID**.

[Existem 2 formas de trabalhar com hierarquia no MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), são elas:

1. Adjacency List Mode
2. Nested Set Model

Eu havia optado por utilizar no meu projeto o *Nested Set Model*, por ter maior desempenho nas consultas, não precisando gerar uma *QUERY* para cada nó quando vou buscar todos os cadastros em hierarquia. No *Nested Set Model* eu vi só uma desvantagem: é preciso atualizar os valores *LEFT* e *RIGHT* de todos os cadastros quando um novo cadastro é realizado.

**Dúvida:**

Qual a melhor alternativa? Perder desempenho na hora do cadastro do usuário, sendo que vou precisar dar um *UPDATE* em cada cadastro(**+50000**) utilizando o *Nested List Model* ou perder desempenho na hora das consultas utilizando o *Adjacency List Model*?

Nesse caso, eu deveria utilizar o *Adjacency List Model* já que os cadastros são dinâmicos?

O *Nested List Model* só seria útil quando a hierarquia é estática, como por exemplo categorias de produtos?